# What happened to the rename song iTunes keyboard shortcut?

Tags: itunes, keyboard

The keyboard shortcut that used to enter rename mode for the currently selected song no longer works in iTunes. Has it changed, or disappeared?

Answer (score 1):

Pressing <kbd>⌤ enter</kbd> / <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>↩ return</kbd> always works for me…

In addition, <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> + <kbd>↩ return</kbd> also works *most of the time*.

[image: Screenshot: Editing a Song Title]